# Detach Label and Append label

Tags: jquery

I have labels as following. I have to detach and append it to div.

```js
var i = 1;
jQuery('.tm-radio').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('tm-radio-'+i);
    var label = jQuery('.tm-radio').next('label');
    label.detach();

    jQuery('.tm-radio-'+i).append(label);
    i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="1">
</div>
<label>Label 1</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="2">
</div>
<label>Label 2</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="3">
</div>
<label>Label 3</label>
```

I have to move label to repected div with class tm-radio.

It's appending all labels to .tm-radio-1 div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code lies on this line `var label = jQuery('.tm-radio').next('label');`, here you are getting all label in first iteration itself so it will append all label to the first element. To make it work replace `jQuery('.tm-radio')` with `jQuery(this)` since `this` refers to current element.

Also [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach) is unnecessary since `append()` method moves the actual element.

```
var i = 1;
jQuery('.tm-radio').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass('tm-radio-' + i);
  var label = jQuery(this).next('label');    
  jQuery('.tm-radio-' + i).append(label);
  i++;
});
```

```js
var i = 1;
jQuery('.tm-radio').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass('tm-radio-' + i);
  var label = jQuery(this).next('label');
  jQuery('.tm-radio-' + i).append(label);
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="1">
</div>
<label>Label 1</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="2">
</div>
<label>Label 2</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="3">
</div>
<label>Label 3</label>
```

---

You can even avoid the counter variable and use the index argument in callback to generate unique class names.

```
jQuery('.tm-radio').each(function(i) {
  jQuery(this).addClass('tm-radio-' + i);
  var label = jQuery(this).next('label');    
  jQuery('.tm-radio-' + i).append(label);
});
```

---

You can make it even more simple as follows by simply appending to the current element.

```
jQuery('.tm-radio').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).append(jQuery(this).next('label'));
});
```

```js
jQuery('.tm-radio').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).append(jQuery(this).next('label'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="1">
</div>
<label>Label 1</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="2">
</div>
<label>Label 2</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="3">
</div>
<label>Label 3</label>
```

Much more simple with [`append()` method with a callback](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function) which iterates internally.

```
jQuery('.tm-radio').append(function() {
  return jQuery(this).next('label');
});
```

```js
jQuery('.tm-radio').append(function() {
  return jQuery(this).next('label');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="1">
</div>
<label>Label 1</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="2">
</div>
<label>Label 2</label>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="3">
</div>
<label>Label 3</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, it's by assuming you have the same number of label and the same number of div.
With the code below you will be able to be more flexible about how your dom is. 
For example all your label can be in the end of your file or anywhere in the DOM.

```js
let label_dom = $("label"); //getting all label elements;
let radio_dom = $(".tm-radio");

function labelInRadioDom() {
  label_dom.each(function(index) {

    radio_dom[index].append(label_dom[index]); // append the label to the good Div (1st label go in the 1st Div, 2nd to the 2nd etc ...)

  })
}


labelInRadioDom();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="1">
</div>

<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="2">
</div>

<div class="tm-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="achieve" class="input-radio" value="3">
</div>
<label>Label 1</label>
<label>Label 2</label>
<label>Label 3</label>
```